# Java Insert Into Table in other Schema

Tags: java, sql, properties, schema, sql-insert

While using INSERT and SELECT to other schema in SQL Developer I'm able to INSERT and SELECT without problem because of Synonym, but if I try to do the same within java code it says:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Connection is done through

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

properties loaded from app.properties file

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties");
```

Comment: If you are using the same SQL and the same user both in Java and SQL Developer then it should work. There is no special way how Java processes synonyms or queries to other schemas

Comment: unfortunatelly same user same pwd and same host SID and port... what else?

Comment: Misprint in SQL while copying it to Java code? I'm using that approach with synonyms to tables/packages in another schema and it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you put the schema and table name instead of the synonym?

e.g. SELECT * FROM HR.OFFICES (instead of SELECT * FROM SYNONYM_FOR_OFFICES)

If that doesn't work either, then the issue is with the database name or credentials as suggested by plucins.

Answer (score 0):

It will work by connecting through Properties with includeSynonyms = true

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.put("user", user);
info.put("password", pwd);
info.put ("includeSynonyms", "true");
```

and then by using the Properties for connection

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, info);
```

in this way it will work